# How to make a continuous current from a flashing source?

Tags: dc, 12v

I have a machine running, when a problem occurs, it stops and sends a 12VDC light bulb flashing every second or so, how can I get a constant signal from it to use this signal in the VFD to perform a short time deceleration, I want to do this to differentiate between a normal stop and an emergency stop.

Comment: one-shot timer.

Comment: Bad joke: remove the power source

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to modify the light bulb, ads some circuitery to detect (check DKNguyen's comment) or something else?

Comment: We need more information. Do you want to use the light from the bulb to generate electricity? Do you want to connect something to the bulb? If so, in series or parallel? What kind of signal exactly? How would you know that the bulb had stopped flashing so the "constant signal" can stop?

Comment: I added more information.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpHKDq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You're looking for a "monostable" or "one shot" timer with a Reset input.  More specifically, it needs to be a retriggerable monostable, so that a flashing input will keep the output "on".  Set the timeout on the timer to slightly more than one second.

Answer (score 3):

Latch the flash using a relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMpeEX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The circuit.*

- When the lamp flashes D1 passes current to the coil of RLY1.
- When the relay energises a normally open contact closes and applies 12 V to the coil which now remains on even when the lamp turns off.
- D1 prevents the hold-on from keeping the light on. It will blink of turn off as normal.
- Meanwhile the VFD stop circuit is interrupted. (Stop inputs are usually  wired so that if the stop wire falls off or gets cut the drive stops for safety.)
- The circuit can be reset by interrupting the 12 V supply with the RESET button. Alternatively another control signal and relay can perform the interruption.

Comment: Thank you, ""When the relay energizes a normally open contact closes and applies 12 V to the coil which now remains on even when the lamp turns off."" can't result in a short circuit?

Comment: Where on my schematic do you see the potential for s short circuit?

Comment: In the NO contact with 12v from to sides, or am I wrong?

Comment: If you connect two wires to the +12 terminal of your car battery and then touch the other ends of the wires together what will happen?

Comment: Nothing will happen!

Comment: Correct. I have I have added an explanation of what D1 is for.

Comment: Now I understand you, but the problem remains in the RESET part, the machine is big and I can't install o lot of reset buttons in every corner of it.

Comment: There isn't enough information or user requirement specification in your question for me to give a better answer.